# Why my local variable change in Python definition while creating nodes?

Tags: python, variables, nodes, local, minimax

I was trying to create nodes of minimax algorithm. However, I was debugging the function and I saw that my local variable 'newstate' changes when the 'state' changes. Is there something that I should know about python? Because I am a new programmer and I want to know why it changes. Thank you for your time.

```
def successorsgenerator(state):

    state=list(state)
    print (state)
    state[-1]=toggle(state[-1])
    print (state)
    newstate=state
    i=0
    while newstate[0]>=0 and i<3:

        state.append(tuple(newstate))
        newstate[0] -= 1
        i+=1

        print(state)

    print('result', state)

def toggle(state):
  state = 'min' if state == 'max' else 'max'
  return state


successorsgenerator(5,'max')
```

result>> [2, 'min', (5, 'min'), (4, 'min', (5, 'min')), (3, 'min', (5, 'min'), (4, 'min', (5, 'min')))]

Comment: You set `newstate = state`

Comment: `newstate=state` literally means that `newstate` *is* `state`. That doesn't create a copy. You've said that they're the same object. You need to create a copy.

Comment: @chrisz but it is before the loop?  does it still affect?

Comment: @Carcigenicate how can I create a new copy?

Comment: @VuralErdogan It does effect it even though it's before the loop because again, you're saying that they're literally the same list. Any changes made to one will effect the other.